# Clickable Chart in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to create a pie chart with linked sheet but when I am clicking on the graph I am getting some error, "Compile error Argument not optional" on the "WorkSheetFunction.Index" line of the code.
I am beginner in VBA coding.. Please help
this is my code
[xl page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auii0.jpg)

**ThisWorkbook module**

```
Dim ChartObjectClass As New Class1
Dim ChartObjectClass2 As New Class2

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ChartObjectClass.ChartObject = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set ChartObjectClass2.ChartObject = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(2).Chart
End Sub
```

**Class module**

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ChartObject As Chart

Private Sub ChartObject_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, _
    ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
    Dim myX As Variant, myY As Double
    With ActiveChart
        .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2
        If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
            If Arg2 > 0 Then
                myX=WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues.Arg2)
                myY=WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values.Arg2)
                MsgBox "Series" & Arg1 & vbCrLf & """" & .SeriesCollection(Arg1)_
                    .Name & """" & vbCrLf & "Point" & Arg2 & vbCrLf & _
                        "x= " & myX & vbCrLf & "y= " & myY
                Range("A1").Select
                On Error Resume Next
                Sheets("Series" & myX & "Detail").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]* I think when learning a programming language it's important to begin with the fundamentals and become comfortable with basic syntax and common coding methods before moving into the advanced concepts - in this case Class modules & catching `WithEvents`. There are changes from the original code that I don't understand, one example being how you are referring to custom types `Class1` and `Class2`, which do not exist in either your code, nor the original.

Comment: ...if you're going to carry on maybe start with an simpler way to do this like [Chart Object Events](//docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/chart-object-events).  Better yet, start with learning VBA, perhaps with [**Excel VBA For Beginners**](//www.homeandlearn.org/) and [Microsoft's Documentation](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/vba-language-reference) (This assumes you are already "very comfortable" with using Excel worksheets.)  Also, plese see what's on-topic here at the [help/on-topic], as well as "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].  *Good Luck!*

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Index requires two arguments.  The first argument specifies the array of values from which to return a value.  The second argument specifies the nth element from the array to return.

```
myX = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)
myY = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)
```

By the way, you can also dispense with the use of WorksheetFunction.Index...

```
myX = .SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues()(Arg2)
myY = .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values()(Arg2)
```